# Amazon S3 UploadPartRequest

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload files to Amazon S3, nothing special. I have managed to do the actual upload, and the file uploads successfully. But i have to upload files Via Amazon S3 UploadPart Request

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear. Have you had a look at this doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/UploadPartRequest.html

Comment: I am able to simple upload request but now i am trying to upload multiple files to amazon not even single. So how can i achieve this thing.

Comment: Currently how do you upload so I can see if you can workaround your current upload method.

Do you intend to auto-update or manual upload

Comment: I know your question hasn't been answered for a while. Have a look at the [Amazon AWS Data Pipeline](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/what-is-datapipeline.html)

Comment: Note, the AWS Data Pipeline is currently available to US region